# Is it possible to call Sonar ScanSner every time merge request is submitted in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

Is there any way Gitlab can call Sonar scanner every time merge request is submitted for the particular project.

I know a way Gitlab webhook can call Jenkins job & in Jenkins job can call sonar scanner as a build step, But here I want to bypass Jenkins involvement.

Answer (score 0):

A [GitLab webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) won't call anything: it will send to an IP address a JSON payload describing a GitLab event (like a push)

From there, you listener (like [`kolomiichenko/gitlab-webhooker`](https://github.com/kolomiichenko/gitlab-webhooker)) can call Sonar itself (or any other command, for that matter).
That command/script executed by the listener would:

- go to a local copy of the repo
- call `git pull` to update itself
- call [Sonar Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

No Jenkins required.

Comment: This method is not working for me, I am calling the url but every time it says  `400 resource not found`
<br/>
here is what I did, <br/>
1.Downloaded **gitlab-webhooker** package.<br/>
2.Installed required package using `npm install`<br/>
3.Started node using 'node filename.js'.<br/>
4.Configured same url in Gitlab webhooks.<br/>